# continuous to categorical 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to convert a continuous 2D numpy array to categories based on thresholds.  When I use the pandas `cut` function I first have to `flatten` to a 1D array and then use `cut`, but the output will not reshape back to 2D with the numpy `reshape` function.

Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(2,3)
print(a)

b = a.flatten()
print(b)

c = pd.cut(b,(0,0.5,1),labels=[0,1])
print(c)

d = np.reshape(c,(2,3))
print(d)
```

The output is

```
[[ 0.56887807  0.1368459   0.34892358]
[ 0.77157277  0.64827644  0.42259086]]
[ 0.56887807  0.1368459   0.34892358  0.77157277  0.64827644  0.42259086]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
Categories (2, int64): [0 < 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
Categories (2, int64): [0 < 1]
```

The `d` array remains 1D even after the reshape command. How can I reshape it back to 2D?

Comment: I've tried your code and `reshape` works fine.

Comment: I tried it as well, works fine for me also.

Comment: It didn't work for me.. maybe due to oldish numpy/pandas versions (1.13.3 / 0.18.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not tied to use pandas' `Categorical` features you can simply use [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to directly convert the 2D array into categorical (integer) values:

Applied to the simple example:

```
c = np.digitize(a, bins=(0.5, 1))
print(c)
# [[1 0 0]
#  [1 1 0]]
```